# Import a progress 4gl file which contains multiple procedure inside a procedure

Tags: rest, openedge, progress-4gl

In this code, the procedure `p-updateCoilStatus` is mapped in a rest API. For now the `v-xusec` in {`x\xxxxllogin.i v-xusec}` is static. I have assigned a value of "web" to it. I want to send value to `v-xusec` through the API. For that I need to keep `{x\xxxxllogin.i v-xusec}` inside the procedure `p-updateCoilStatus` because the API doesn't look outside the procedure.  When I try to keep  `{x\xxxxllogin.i v-xusec}` inside the procedure I get an error saying:

> "YOU CANNOT NEST PROCEDURES, METHODS AND FUNCTIONS"

because `x\xxxxllogin.i` contains multiple procedure and functions.

I WANT TO MAKE THE VARIABLE `v-xusec` DYNAMIC FROM THE API.

```
@openapi.openedge.export FILE(type="REST", executionMode="single-run", useReturnValue="false",       writeDataSetBeforeImage="false").

{src\emmDataset.i}
@openapi.openedge.export(type="REST", useReturnValue="false", writeDataSetBeforeImage="false").
procedure p-updateCoilStatus:
define input parameter coilNumber as character no-undo.
define input parameter xusec as character no-undo.
define input-output parameter table for ttCoilRecord.

define variable v-stacDamaged as character no-undo.
define variable v-stacAvailable as character no-undo.
define variable v-oldcoilstatus as character no-undo.
define variable v-newcoilstatus as character no-undo.
define variable v-ocoin as character no-undo.
define variable v-smtpServer as character no-undo.
define variable v-mailTo as character no-undo.
define variable v-mailFrom as character no-undo.

define buffer buff_ocoil for ocoil.

assign 
       v-ocoin         = substring(coilNumber,2,length(coilNumber))
       v-smtpServer    = f-xsysfield("xsystsmtp")
       v-mailTo        = f-xsysfield("dmgControl")
       v-mailFrom      = f-xsysfield("xsystfrom").


find ocoil where ocoil.xlevc = f-xlevc("ocoil") and ocoil.ocoin = integer(v-ocoin) no-lock no-error.
if avail ocoil then 
do:
    assign v-stacDamaged   = f-xstanext('ocoil',ocoil.xstac,10,TRUE,?)
           v-stacAvailable = f-xstanext('ocoil',ocoilxstac,20,TRUE,?)
           v-oldcoilstatus = ocoil.xstac.
    
    find ttCoilRecord no-lock.
    if not available ttCoilRecord then leave.
    
    if (v-oldcoilstatus = v-stacDamaged) or (v-oldcoilstatus = v-stacAvailable) then
    do:
    end.
    else
    do:
        find buff_ocoil where buff_ocoil.xlevc = f-xlevc('ocoil')
                          and buff_ocoil.ocoin = ocoil.ocoin 
                          exclusive-lock.
        assign 
            buff_ocoil.glocc = ttCoilRecord.glocc
            buff_ocoil.xstac = if ttCoilRecord.xstac = "Damaged" then v-stacDamaged  else v-     stacAvailable.
        release buff_ocoil.
    end.
     
     assign v-newcoilstatus = ocoil.xstac.
              
     assign ttCoilRecord.glocc = ocoil.glocc
            ttCoilRecord.xstac = if ocoil.xstac = "225" then "Damaged"  else trim(entry(2,entry(1,f-           xstadisp("ocoil",ocoil.xstac)), "-")).
     end.
     
     if v-newcoilstatus = "225" and v-oldcoilstatus < "225" then
     do:
     end.

end procedure.
}

{x\xxxxllogout.i}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your work, now try removing all the noise which is irrelevant.

Comment: Some more detail on what the contents of {x\xxxxllogin.i v-xusec} looks like would be usefule to help answer this. Doesn't have to be the entire include, but, given the error you're seeing, any procedure or function blocks, as well as the variable you're trying to reference.